# What is the list of filetypes included on " image/* "?

Tags: html, file-type

I have an input control in my HTML that accepts only image files, however many times it is failing because of the filetype uploaded.

```
<input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" accept="image/*"/>
```

I know that the attribute accept="image/*" limits the number of the files accepted but does anyone know what filetypes in terms of extensions are for sure accepted in here (e.g. .png, .jpg, and so on)?

Comment: Most likely, anything that the browser auto-detection identifies as picture. What problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: here is the list of all knows mime types: https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/. There you can search for "image/"

Comment: I don't know what type of files they are uploading but sometime is failing. I tried to upload myself some of the file types and works fine. I was thinking if there was a list of at least the most common file types included on that attribute so I can show a message with allowed type of files.

Comment: A file upload won't fail just for the file format, unless the file size exceeds certain limits or you have some server-side security software that aborts the upload (for instance, because it identifies it as malware). There's something else you aren't saying. My guess is that you try to display it in HTML or generate a thumbnail and that's what fails, not the upload.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you are correct. I was trying to use it as a thumbnail and that is the reason why was generating an error.

Comment: Then it's pointless to browse the HTML5 specs or the browser source code. Instead, read the documentation of whatever thumbnail tool you are using and write a fallback mechanism to notify user of invalid pictures.